# Does every 550 GTX Ti support two big screens?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, resolution

I need a video card which will support 2 2560x1440 monitors. Also, it has to be nVidia, because I promised myself that I won't touch fglrx any more. Now that the 550 GTX Ti is finally available, there is a card within my price limit which looks nice.

I know that with previous series, it was possible that a card with two DVI outputs doesn't support two big monitors at full resolution. Is it still like this? Do I have to find out the supported resolution for the particular model I am buying, or can I rest assured that if it has a combination of two DVI, HDMI or Display Ports, or a mix of them, it also supports the full resolution on two monitors?

Comment: I assume you're wanting to run on linux then? Be careful as depending on what technology you use, the maximum desktop size may be limited to 4096x4096.

Comment: @PriceChild I use Ubuntu (gnome) with the proprietary nvidia drivers, is that OK for more than 4096x4096?

Comment: I'm not sure and its worth researching. I'm running Ubuntu (gnome) with an intel card and hit the limit.

Comment: Here's a bit of info: http://techfrp.blogspot.com/2010/09/xrandr-desktop-scaling-for-ubuntu.html

Comment: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2 - probably a better source states "Note that the maximum supported size of the virtual desktop for the Intel 945GM series of chipset with 3D acceleration enabled, is 2048x2048. The virtual screen can be larger but DRI will be disabled. This may matter if you like games and compiz desktop effects, or if you want Google Earth to display in better than geological time." I don't know what the maximum will be for the 550, but it will have a limit.

Comment: Or maybe I'm being silly... I don't think you go with xrandr with the nvidia drivers actually. They won't have the same reason for the limit but I'm guessing they'll still have one judging by the google results for windows users. Sorry its been a while since I've messed with this, I'll be quiet now!

Comment: It isn't possible to create a xrandr screen with the proprietary nvidia drivers, I found this out some time back. So if there is a limit, it will be in the nvidia package. I can't find one in the documentation.

Comment: You are not silly, thanks for the information, I hadn't considered that there may be a problem from this side. I'll look into it more before buying.